# How do I detect the result of a quiet install using the standard WiX bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, wix3.11, wixstdba

I have created an installer using WiXStandardBootstrapperApplication. If I run it in a command window with /quiet, the command window returns immediately to the prompt and the install continues in the background, so I can't use ERRORLEVEL to check the result of the install. How can I know if the install succeeded? More importantly, how can some system management tool that is pushing the install out to many PCs know if it succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the following at the command line:

```
msiexec installer.msi /quiet /l*v logfile.txt
```

This will perform a quiet install, and you can then check the resulting log file to see if the install succeeded or failed.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear enough, but that misses the point on two counts. Firstly, I'm dealing with a WiX bootstrapper (AKA burn); it contains multiple MSIs. Secondly, I need the software pushing the install to be able to detect the result (and to know when it completes).